# SQL Aggregate function issues using DISTINCT function

Tags: sql-server

I'm needing help with a question that I've been racking my brain on for two days now (Almost), on this assignment. I'm still pretty new to SQL and I'm just struggling.

I DO NOT WANT THE ANSWER!! I'm just looking for help getting going in the right direction.

Here is the question:

**Write a SELECT statement that answers this question: Which customers have ordered more than one product? Return these columns:
The email address from the Customers table
The count of distinct products from the customer’s orders**

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID,
       Count(DISTINCT ProductID) AS ProductsCount
FROM   Customers
       INNER JOIN Orders
               ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
       JOIN Products
         ON Products.ProductID = OrderItems.ProductID
GROUP  BY Customers.CustomerID,
          Orders.CustomerID
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
    Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
    The multi-part identifier "OrderItems.ProductID" could not be bound.
```

The structure of the three tables in play here is.

The Customer table has an Emailaddress and CustomerID column.
The Orders table has CustomerID and OrderID columns.
The Products table has ProductID column.
The OrderItems table has OrderID, ProductID, and Quantity columns.

Any Help would be really really helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't join `OrderItems` Table. Thats y u got that error!!

Answer (score 1):

Fix the syntax as suggested by joining to the OrderItems table and in order to look for something more than once, you need to use group by field1, field2, etc. having count(field) > 1. You are almost there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tip to find the answer,

1. find the orders which has has more than one item in `OrderItems`
   table by using `having clause` with `Count() aggregate` and `Group by orderID`.
2. so from the first step you will have the orders that have more than
       one item and count of products in every order. next join the first step result with
       order table to get the customerid.
3. next join the second step result with customers table to get the
       customers information who bought more than one one product in single
       order with count.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there :-)

- You forgot to join OrderItems.
- You don't need the table Products in this query (you don't want to see anything from that table; you get the product count from OrderItems).
- To limit by aggregates (as by the number of products here) use HAVING.
- To group by Orders.CustomerID is superfluous, as it equals Customers.CustomerID.